# Boost Installation

Tags: c++, boost, installation

Is there a quick way to run the various test files in the Boost installation directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided is years old, and quite likely out of date. For the current instructions, see here instead: http://beta.boost.org/development/running_regression_tests.html

Answer (score 0):

Found it: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/runner/instructions.html